# Approximating random variables without invertible CDF

Tags: probability-theory, approximation, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose that I have a function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that for any random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$, and with invertible CDF, $\mathbb{E}[f(X)] \leq 0$.

Is it possible to give conditions on the function $f$ so that I can ensure that this inequality holds more generally for any random variable with mean $\mu$ and possibly noninvertible CDF?

One thought I had would possibly work for continuous $f$.
Specifically, let $Y$ be some random variable with mean $\mu$, and such that its CDF is possibly not invertible. Perhaps one could construct random variables $Y_n$ each of which have invertible CDF, and have mean $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = \mu$. Then, applying the inequality for $Y_n$, we would get $\mathbb{E}[f(Y_n)] \leq 0$, and therefore if say $f$ is continuous and $Y_n \to Y$ almost surely, then one would obtain $\mathbb{E}[Y] \leq 0$.

In this case, one would need to find a way to some how cook up $Y_n$ with invertible CDFs such that $Y_n \to Y$ almost surely, and $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = \mu$.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the condition $\mathbb E[f(X)]\le 0$ has to do with the invertibility/non invertibility of the CDF of $X$. If you want that this condition holds for *every* RV $X$ it must hold for every constant $X$. This implies $f(x)\le 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. This is obviously a necessary and sufficient condition.
BTW: even though it is unrelated please note that every CDF has at least a [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_(quantile_function)):

Comment: No, I do not want it to hold for every $X$, just those with $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mu$.  I agree that $f(\mu) \leq 0$ is necessary, by considering the r.v. with constant value $\mu$. Finally, my question is asking SUPPOSE $\mathbb{E}[f(X)] \leq 0$ holds for any $X$ with mean $\mu$ and with invertible CDF (not just in the generalized sense). Then, does $\mathbb{E}[f(X)] \leq 0$ hold for all $X$ with mean $\mu$ (dropping the invertibility criterion)? If not, what additional properties does $f$ need to satisfy?